# Maximum call stack size exceeded - saving to GridFS - no recursion happening

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I'm trying to save a file into GridFS in node.js.
The usecase is actually really straight forward: "upload a file to a restify app, save it into GridFS".

```
function put(req, res, next) {
    var ws, filename;

    var application = new Application(req.params);
    if (req.files.cv) {
        filename = application._id + '/' + req.files.cv.name;
        ws = gfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: filename,
            content_type: req.files.cv.type
        });

        ws.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log('could not save: ', error);
        });

        fs.createReadStream(req.files.cv.path).pipe(ws);
        application.files.push(filename);
    }
    /* cut */
    application.save(function (err, application) {
        /* cut */
        next();
    });
}
```

The console tells me

```
could not save:  [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
```

and since this is fired from an event, I don't have a stacktrace. Anyway nothing is written into GridFS.

Since on my part there is no recursion, I thought it has to be on [gridfs-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gridfs-stream) or mongodb's side, and since those are tested, I tried to simply higher the `--stack-size`, this resulted in a Segmentation Fault.

This is my environtment: https://github.com/semmypurewal/node-dev-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Clean up NPM dependencies

I've updated all dependencies (mongodb, mongoose, gridfs-stream) to their latest version: did not help.

What helped:
mongoose `require()`s mongodb, it creates it's own little instance. If you `require()` your own mongodb, you somehow f*ck everything up. Don't do it.

- Only `require()` mongoose.
- Remove `mongodb` from your `package.json`
- Remove `mongodb` from `node_modules`.

If for some reason you need a reference to `mongodb` (for example for `gridfs-stream`), mongoose is nice enough to share its own with you.

**Before:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var mongo = require('mongodb'); // BAD BOY! BAD! 
//...
var gfs = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongo);
```

**After:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var mongo = mongoose.mongo; // I LIKE, SO NICE!
//...
var gfs = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongo);
```